# Non zero solution of $3x\cos(x) + (-3 + x^2)\sin(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series, elementary-functions

How can I find exact non-zero solution of $3x\cos(x) + (-3 + x^2)\sin(x)=0$. Simple analysis and the below plot show that the equation has an infinite number of non-zero solutions.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the equation of $\frac{J_\frac52(x)}{J_{-\frac52}(x)}=a$ with Bessel J

Answer (score 2):

There's probably no closed-form solution for the real roots you're looking for, although you have a chance with the complex solutions.

Let's notice that $3x \cos x$ and $\left( x^2 - 3 \right) \sin x$ have the same trigonometric argument. That means that the [Harmonic Addition Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicAdditionTheorem.html) can be used: we can rewrite this as one trigonometric function.

HAT states that
\begin{align}a \cos x + b \sin x &= A \cos \left(x + B \right),
\end{align}
where $a^2 + b^2 = A^2$ and $-\frac{b}a = \tan B$.

So, substituting $3x \cos x$ for $a$ and $x^2 - 3$ for $b$, we find that $A^2 = x^4 + 3x^2 + 9$ and $\frac{3 - x^2}{3x} = \tan B$.

This of course has infinitely many solutions, although the factor of $A$ only contributes some complex roots. Ignoring questions of signs and branch choice, let's declare that $A = \sqrt{x^4 + 3x^2 + 9}$ and $B = \tan^{-1} \frac{3 - x^2}{3x}$, or in other words
$$3x \cos x + (x^2 - 3) \sin x = \sqrt{x^4 + 3x^2 + 9} \cos \left( x + \tan^{-1} \frac{3 - x^2}{3x} \right).$$

The problem can therefore be rewritten as finding the zeroes of $\sqrt{x^4 + 3x^2 + 9}$ and $\cos \left( x + \tan^{-1} \frac{3 - x^2}{3x} \right)$, although I doubt you'll find any good closed form for the latter.

[This WolframAlpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bsqrt(x%5E4%20%2B%203x%5E2%20%2B%209)cos(x%20%2B%20arctan((3%20-%20x%5E2)%2F(3x))),%20%7Bx,%200,%2060%7D%5D) looks like it agrees with your image.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice manipulation. But still the expression $\sqrt(x^4+3x^2+9)=0$ doesn't have the reql solutions. I will try to work with other factor

Answer (score 1):

There is an infinite number of solutions.  Choose one region and find a solution there:

```
FindMinimum[Abs[3 x Cos[x] + (x^2 - 3) Sin[x]], {x, 9.5}] // Quiet
```

$\{\text{1.6217274456664654$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7},\{x\to 5.76346\}\}$

[image]

Comment: I need an exact closed form solution, which could be in the form of a series.

Comment: I don't see how it is possible for a series to yield an infinite number of solutions.  Good luck!

Comment: I am looking for just one solution.

Comment: I formed an algebraic expression for tan(x), and then used it in conjuction with the taylor series for arctan(x), but couldn't get anywhere.  I think the solution lies in exploring the **context of the question** more deeply.  If this is a problem from a textbook, you would attempt to use the methods introduced in the pages leading up to the problem.  Failing that, another approach would be to try to find $f(x)$ so that some clever manipulation of either $d[f(x)]/dx$ or $\int f(x)dx$ helps you to achieve a closed form solution.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork a 2nd try is $3x \cos(x) = (3-x^2)\sin(x).$  Square both sides and substitute $1 - \cos^2(x) = \sin^2(x).$  This leads to an equation like $(x^4 + ax^2 + b)(\cos^2(x) = (x^4 + cx^2 + d).$  Unfortunately, I can't see anyway to use such an equation, and I don't see how (for example) attempting to combine the taylor series for cosine with the equation would help.

Comment: @user2661923:  No amount of manipulation can alter the topological/algebraic fact that there is an infinite number of solutions to this problem.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork agreed, but that fact does not imply that the problem won't succumb to taylor series expansion or manipulation of $d[f(x)]/dx$ or $\int f(x)dx.$  For example, the taylor series for $\cos(x)$ converges to 0 at an infinite number of points.

Comment: @user2661923:  So what is the benefit of having an infinite series?  After all, $x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^8\right)$ has an infinite number of values of $x$ where the infinite sum is $0$ (since it is $\sin x$).  How does that help?

Comment: @user2661923 This is not the problem in a textbook. This arouse from a research problem where I want to make certain integral vanish. My expression is the factor in the result which I got after solving my integral. I think I should just show in my project that the root exists rather than finding the exact one.

Comment: I already proved that a root exists.  [All this seems very confusing and wandering.]

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "So what is the benefit of having an infinite series?...How does that help?"  Given my limited math abilities, it would not help at all.  I presented it as : (1) all that I could come up with and (2) an idea that someone with better math abilities might run with.

Comment: @user2661923:  My (perhaps-more-informed) opinion is that having a series will not help at all.  Frankly, I get the sense that your real question is something other than what you asked, and that if we knew what your fundamental problem was, then we could help.  But that's up to you.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I am not the OP.  My (very informal) thinking is that there is a way of initially defining sine and cosine via their taylor series and then proving that each taylor series has a period of $2\pi.$  My idea was to use the taylor series to convert the OP's original equation into an infinite series and then (somehow) identify in closed form for which points the series converges to 0.

Comment: Dear all, I know one of the non-elementary methods to solve it. It is through Lagrange's inverse theorem using the series solution. So I would need to generate power series for my function. I think that will work. I tried to avoid this method.

Comment: @ersh:  Be sure to let us see this solution, if you ever obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

I am certain that
there is no exact solution to this.
However,
by looking at regions where either
$\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ is small,
I think that it can be shown that
$f(x)
=3x\cos(x) + (-3 + x^2)\sin(x)
$
will change sign in these regions.

In particular,
let $x = n\pi+y$
where $y$ is small.

Then
$\sin(x) = \sin(y)
\approx y$.

Also,
$\cos(x)
=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}
=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(y)}
\approx\sqrt{1-y^2}
\approx 1-\frac{y^2}{2}
$.

Similarly,
if $x = (n+\frac12)\pi+y$
where $y$ is small.

Then
$\cos(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)
\approx y$
and
$\sin(x)
\approx 1-\frac{y^2}{2}
$.

Try each of these in $f(x)$
and see which can be made small
by making $y$ small.

Answer (score 0):

Since we use [Bessel J](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselJ%285%2F2%2Cx%29):

$$3x\cos(x)+(x^2-3)\sin(x)=0\iff-\frac{\sqrt\frac2\pi}{x^\frac52}(3x\cos(x)+(x^2-3)\sin(x))=\text J_\frac52(x)=0$$

The solution uses [Bessel J Zero $\text j_{v,x}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselJZero):

$$3x\cos(x)+(x^2-3)\sin(x)=0 \iff x=\text j_{\frac52,\Bbb N}$$

where the $n$th natural number gives the $n$th solution [**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B3+BesselJZero%5B5%2F2%2C+x%5D+Cos%5BBesselJZero%5B5%2F2%2C+x%5D%5D+%2B+%28-3+%2B+BesselJZero%5B5%2F2%2C+x%5D%5E2%29+Sin%5BBesselJZero%5B5%2F2%2C+x%5D%5D%2C20%5D%2Cx%3D39)